# Insert elements from a set to an array (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set (S) of numbers and I want to put this numbers in an array (arr) . I tried this code

```
Arr = np.array(S)
```

but I can't access to arrays element, for example if I try

> Arr[0]

, I get this error:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

Can anyone explain what is the problem with this approach and is there any other way that I can use in order to put the elements of set in array and access to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to convert your set of numbers to a list.

```
S = {1, 2, 3}

>>> np.array(S)
array(set([1, 2, 3]), dtype=object)

>>> np.array(list(S))
array([1, 2, 3])
```